# Add text above the registration form on user/register page

Tags: forms, users

Is there a way to add a message above the Registration Form?

I know you can edit the field by going to "Configuration/People/Account Setting/Manage Field", but how about a message above the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to create a block that is only displayed for that page, and position it above the content.

Comment: OMG, i forgot about the "block". TY @Graham :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div><p>'. t('Add your message here'). '</p></div>';
}
```

Read also [Customizing and Overriding User Login page, Register, and Password Reset in Drupal 6 and 7](https://drupal.org/node/350634) : another way to add your message and whatever you'd like:

> Customizing the user login, register, and password reset pages is
>   fairly simple, and uses the following concepts:
>
> - preprocessing to set variables
> - registration of functions in the theme registry
> - creation of one or more theme templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use markup like this

```
<?php

 function first_admin_setting_form($node, &$form_state) {
      $form = array();
      $form['overview'] = array(
        '#markup' => t('Interface for setting for first module'),
          '#prefix' => '<h4>',
          '#suffix' => '</h4>',
        );
?>
```